# Dompdf tables with empty cells

Tags: dompdf

I am trying to create a PDF that contains table which is partly filled, partly empty. To accomplish this I am using [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) via a [Laravel wrapper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

It seems that DomPDF somehow miscalculates the height of the empty cells and also displaces the table grid and content.

Here is a minimal broken example:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
   font-family: DejaVu Sans;
  }
  
  table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   border: none;
            margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
  }
  
  table.main td {
            padding: 0;
   border: 2px solid black;
  }
  
  .main table td {
   border: 1px black solid;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 10px;
   height: 14px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <table class="main">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr><td>1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>2</td></tr>
     <tr><td>3</td></tr>
     <tr><td>4</td></tr>
     <tr><td>5</td></tr>
     <tr><td>6</td></tr>
     <tr><td>7</td></tr>
     <tr><td>8</td></tr>
     <tr><td>9</td></tr>
     <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>
    <table>
     <tr><td>1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>2</td></tr>
     <tr><td>3</td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how that table looks like in the generated PDF:

[image]

I have tried to add `min-height` and `max-height` for the table cell, but no results, it still randomly misaligns everything.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this requires `line-height` to be set exactly equal to the font size. This will work:

```
.main table td {
        border: 1px black solid;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 10px;
        height: 14px;
    }
```

Comment: It's true that the min/max height declarations don't work too well right now when used with tables. In addition to setting the line height, you could also supply a non-printing character (e.g. `&nbsp;`) to fill the space with sized content to expand the cell.